# XSLT: apply a template to a tree fragment

Tags: xslt, node-set

I have defined a variable $NodeVariable, 
for instance:

```
<xsl:variable name="NodeVariable">
    <aT>
        <aT2>foo</aT2>
        <aT3>bar</aT3>
    </aT>
</xsl:variable>
```

and in different parts of the code I want to "apply" 
different templates to myVariable. 
Unfortunately, 
I don't know what's the syntax for this.

I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$NodeVariable"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="ns:ExtractInfo1"/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:copy-of select="$NodeVariable"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="ns:ExtractInfo2"/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:copy-of select="$NodeVariable"> 
    <xsl:call-template name="ns:ExtractInfo3"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which doesn't work.

How to apply a template to a tree fragment?

Comment: You've tagged your question `[node-set]` yourself. There's your answer. Use the `node-set()` extension function. How the function can be made available depends on your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use an XSLT 1.0 processor, you need to convert the result tree fragment to a node set first:

```
<xsl:variable name="NodeVariable">
    <aT>
        <aT2>foo</aT2>
        <aT3>bar</aT3>
    </aT>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="NodeSet" select="exsl:node-set($NodeVariable)"/>
```

(where the stylesheet declares `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`), then you can apply-templates in different modes as needed e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$NodeSet/aT" mode="m1"/>
```

and write templates for that mode e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="aT" mode="m1">
  <xsl:value-of select="aT2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course if you really want to call named templates you could do that as well, but using apply-templates and modes for different processing steps is the preferred way in XSLT in my view.

Comment: What if I use an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: @jimifiki, with an XSLT 2.0 processor the distinction between input trees and result tree fragments is gone, your variable would simply be a temporary tree you can process the same way as an input tree and use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="$NodeVariable/aT" mode="m1"/>`.